# Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel working on local but not on heroku composer

Tags: php, excel, heroku, laravel-5

I am trying to upload an Excel file on a laravel build on heroku with package Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel.  I have it installed using composer.  Everything works fine on my local machine.  When I push to the server and run composer install it no longer works.  I have cleared my composer files and re-ran composer install and it still won't work on my heroku server. Below is my answer.  I think it will be something easy that I am not thinking of maybe the scope on my server is different than on my local

> FatalThrowableError in ExcelServiceProvider.php line 221:
>
> Class 'PHPExcel_Settings' not found in ExcelServiceProvider.php line 221

Comment: Can you check if the PHP Excel library is included in your project?

Comment: @ronald Yes it is in the project.  I checked on the server.  If I run php artisan tinker with the line that is breaking    $locale = Config::get('app.locale', 'en_us');  PHPExcel_Settings::setLocale($locale);  On the server I do not get the class is missing.

Comment: do you have curl installed on the live server?

Comment: I would suggest installing new packages in your project locally and then push the zip to live server and then extract the zip.

Comment: @RohitDalal Curl is working because all the other packages are getting installed.